# OSAS v4 Open Systems Accounting Software

Tags: unix, database

My company recently purchased another company and along with it, came an old SCO Openserver (v5) running OSAS v4. We use TinyTerm as recommended to access this but no one knows how to use it.  I've been tasked with finding a way to export this data into a more current database.

Does anyone have any ideas om how to do this?

Comment: Find a consultant who is familiar with the software and then hire that person to help you out.

Answer (score 5):

This is more than "export data". You have an ERP system; you can't just simply dump it to CSV and expect to use it in another system. Even if all the fields mapped without a single problem, you don't have the business logic, scheduled jobs/exports, etc.

You should concentrate on finding a replacement product, and then working with the vendor or VAR to help migrate your old data.

Looking at OSAS's site, you could stay with the existing product line, if you like the software, and just upgrade the OS platform to a modern Unix, Linux, or Windows.